# Extension help (key press when running in background)

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am new to making extensions.

For my content script I'm using content.js and for my background script I'm using background.js.

I want it so while my extension runs in the background in google chrome it prints "Hello" when you click "Shift" while on a specific web page.

Current script without extension:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 16) { 
        if (window.location.href == "https://www.google.com") {
            console.log("Hello");
        } else {
            console.log("Go to https://www.google.com");
        }
        console.log("Shift Pressed");
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: `location.href` doesn't need to be accessed through `window`. What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: Not sure where to start :L

I want it so if you click shift on google.com that it console.log("Hello")

Comment: You are using jQuery. Is jQuery loaded by your extension?

Comment: Yeah (jQuery is loaded by my extention). The thing is, I'm not really sure where to put this script, like what file and what I need to put in it to activate it, I've never really made extensions before.

Comment: Have you read [the manual](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)?

Comment: Yeah, just confused of where I should put this.

Comment: Normally you would create a script.js file with your code and then [update manifest.json accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script) (`'content_scripts': [{'js' : ['myScript.js']}]`).

Comment: Yeah, I got that in my manifest.json.

Comment: And you have seen [this reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)? If that's the case, I am not sure what exactly your problem might be. Do you have myScript.js in your extension's root directory?

Comment: Thanks and yeah, I'll try to figure it out on my own, I'll reply if I have any struggles :P

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to help, but without knowing your setup it's hard to be specific.

Comment: so far i have this:

manifest.json:

`{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Supreme Autofill Bot",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.supremenewyork.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ],
 "browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html",
  "default_icon": "icon.png"
 },
 "icons": { 
  "128": "icon.png" 
 },
 "permissions": [
  "https://www.supremenewyork.com/*"
 ],
 "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
 }
}`

but i am not sure where i should put my script.

Comment: Your script should be in the same directory as manifest.json

Comment: `while my extension runs in the background` and `Current script without extension` make no sense. Your extension architecture is represented by two separate parts currently: the content script that runs alongside the web page and that can access the web page and its DOM events like `keydown`, and a background page that is a separate hidden page with its own `document` and `window`, not related to the web page or content script.

Comment: Also, you need to start using devtools debugger properly: you can debug your content script and the background page and step through the code, inspect variables, see what happens instead of blindly guessing and being confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can add content script with patterns (or check url if you want).
In manifest.json : `

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"], //  patterns to check url
  "css": ["mystyles.css"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "yourScript.js"]
}]
```

and in yourScript.js

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 16) { 
            //send to background.js
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({shift: 'true'}, 
                function(response) {
                    // response of background.js onMessage from this message
                });
        }
    });
```

and background page with background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
         // you can check url sender.tab.url  ( if you set patterns is <all_urls>)
        (request.shift == 'true') && console.log("Shift Pressed");
    });
```